# Is there negative impact on using a 301 redirected link as main nav?

Tags: 301-redirect

Is there negative impact on using a 301 redirected link as main nav link?

Current company has Main Nav to Blog as http://hannainst.com/about/company-blog.html (a 301 redirect) to http://hannainst.com/blog/

It works and I don't think it is harming anything on the surface but my gut says Google might not like it.

Comment: Why don't you just link directly to the new URL? Why all the extra overhead?

Comment: I agree. Fix it. Why take a chance that there can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a long held position that 301 links are fine and very appropriate for many situations.  They pass page rank and most sites rely on them for a host of reasons like:

1) page url was update to new url
2) Company was acquired and all their urls now redirect to cooresponding urls on acquirers website
3) Total site redesign in which all urls changed.

Google has stated that the amount of page rank that flows over a 301 is nearly identical to the amount that flows over a straight link.

See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Filv4pP-1nw

Some webmasters feel that there may be slightly more loss due to a 301 than a straight link, but there are no hard numbers, and it's generally thought to be a very tiny loss, perhaps 1%.

So the short answer, is if you can do a straight link do it, but if not, don't lose any sleep over using a 301, it's fine.

Comment: I just learned that there is no longer _any_ penalty for doing redirects so 100% of the page rank is preserved.  Read here for more details: http://searchengineland.com/google-no-pagerank-dilution-using-301-302-30x-redirects-anymore-254608